# Azure data explorer kusto regex

Tags: regex, azure, azure-data-explorer

I am trying to grab a substring from a queryText column. The queryText column is a SQL query statement. And my goal is to parse and extract specific patterns into a new column called TableName.

`parse kind=regex queryText with "[Ff][Rr][Oo][Mm]" TableName`

Above is my current Regex statement. It returns all characters after "FROM" or "from". I would like to only grab characters after "FROM" and before the first whitespace or newline. Any idea on what i have to add to the regex expression to do this?

Comment: StackOverflow is packed with posts that explain why **_not_** to use regex for such a task. Regex could work for simple queries with no edge cases, otherwise you'll need something like [ANTLR](https://www.antlr.org/) (See publicly available [SQL grammers](https://github.com/antlr/grammars-v4/tree/master/sql))

Answer (score 0):

you could use the [`extract()` function](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-explorer/kusto/query/extractfunction).

for example (using the [`i` flag](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-explorer/kusto/query/re2-library#flags) for case-insensitivity):

```
datatable(input:string)
[
    "select * FROM MyTable\n where X > 1",
    "SELECT A,B,C from MyTable",
    "select COUNT(*) from MyTable GROUP BY X",
    "select * FROM MyTable",
    "select * from [a].[b]",
]
| extend output = extract(@"(?i)from\s+([^\s]+)\s*", 1, input)
```

| input | output |
| --- | --- |
| select * from [a].[b] | [a].[b] |
| select * FROM MyTable where X > 1 | MyTable |
| SELECT A,B,C from MyTable | MyTable |
| select COUNT(*) from MyTable GROUP BY X | MyTable |
| select * FROM MyTable | MyTable |

Comment: **\S** is the opposite of **\s**